# Reading a file from Java Submodule android

Tags: java, file

I have created java submodule in android project to do some networking code. I would like to read a file from the same directory as that of my java code. I used the below code,

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/cert.pem").getFile());
```

But it always throws `nullpointer exception` for `getFile`. But `cert.pem` is there in the directory same as the java code. Please do show me some sample code to read a file from the current directory...

Thanks

Comment: If it's in the same directory try adding a dot before the slash: `./cert.pem` and if that still doesn't work - try providing a full path.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.uofr.net/~greg/java/get-resource-listing.html) for a method which will list the contents of the directory you are trying to access.  It will be clear whence you are trying to access `/cert.pem`.